# Como enviar un form a una api desde flutter

Tags: api, flutter

Tengo este codigo en un archivo de vue, en este codigo los datos son enviados a una url de una api. Un formulario es declarado y los datos son cargados en el, int string y archivos de imagenes, entonces el form es enviado a la api, primero se obtienen validan los archivos que ingresa el usuario, despues se colocan los datos en form y se envia a la api, despues de imprime el resultado de la api:

```
async ArtefactoQuemadosPost(tokenGoogle) {
      this.loading = true;
      var DNIFrente = null
      var DNIDorso = null
      var factura = null
      if (this.extractExtFile(this.$v.formComplete.frenteDNI.$model) === ".pdf"){
        DNIFrente = this.$v.formComplete.frenteDNI.$model
      } else {
        DNIFrente = await this.comprimirImagen(this.$v.formComplete.frenteDNI.$model, parseInt(20))
      }
      if (this.extractExtFile(this.$v.formComplete.dorsoDNI.$model) === ".pdf"){
        DNIDorso = this.$v.formComplete.dorsoDNI.$model
      } else {
        DNIDorso = await this.comprimirImagen(this.$v.formComplete.dorsoDNI.$model, parseInt(20))
      }
      if (this.extractExtFile(this.$v.formComplete.factura.$model) === ".pdf"){
        factura = this.$v.formComplete.factura.$model
      } else {
        factura = await this.comprimirImagen(this.$v.formComplete.factura.$model, parseInt(20))
      }

            
      this.url =  this.$store.getters.urlBase + "/Claim/ArtefactoQuemado";

      const form = new FormData();
      form.append("Apellido", this.apellidoTitular);
      form.append("Nombre", this.nombreTitular);
      form.append("DNI", parseInt(this.dni));
      form.append("PUMc", parseFloat(this.$v.formComplete.puMc.$model));
      form.append("NumeroMedidor", parseFloat(this.$v.formComplete.numeroMedidor.$model));
      form.append("Celular",  parseFloat(this.$v.formComplete.celCompleto.$model));
      form.append("Email", this.$v.formComplete.email.$model);
      form.append("FechaDaño", this.fechacompleta);
      form.append("Descripcion", this.$v.formComplete.descripcion.$model);
      form.append("PersonalEdeseTrabajando", this.habiaPersonal);
      if (this.habiaPersonal) {
        form.append("NombrePersonalEdese", this.NombrePersonal);
        form.append("ApellidoPersonalEdese", this.ApellidoPersonal);
        form.append("FechaPersonalEdese", this.fechacompletaPersonal);
      }  

      var index = 0;
      this.artefactos.forEach(element => {
     
        form.append("ArtefactosQuemados["+index+"][NumeroOrden]", parseInt(element.nroOrden));
        form.append("ArtefactosQuemados["+index+"][Tipo]", element.tipo);
        form.append("ArtefactosQuemados["+index+"][Marca]", element.marca);
        form.append("ArtefactosQuemados["+index+"][Modelo]", element.modelo);
        form.append("ArtefactosQuemados["+index+"][NumeroSerie]", element.nroSerie);
        index++;
      });

      form.append("Files", DNIFrente, "DNI-Frente" + this.extractExtFile(this.$v.formComplete.frenteDNI.$model));
      form.append("Files", DNIDorso, "DNI-Dorso"+ this.extractExtFile(this.$v.formComplete.dorsoDNI.$model));
      form.append("Files", factura,  "Factura"+ this.extractExtFile(this.$v.formComplete.factura.$model));

      //  console.log(this.archivosConfirmados)

      const config = {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
           'recaptchaToken': tokenGoogle
        },
      };

      await axios
        .post(this.url, form, config)
        .then((response) => {
          this.respuesta = response;
          this.isSaving = false;
          if (this.respuesta.status === 200) {
            this.$refs.ModalMensaje.Mensaje('Operación realizada correctamente. Nro. de tramite: ' + this.respuesta.data,'Confirmación!', '/', 'success')
     
            this.loading = false;
            //   this.$router.push("/");
          }
        })
        .catch((e) => {
          if (e.response) {
            this.$refs.ModalMensaje.Mensaje(e.response.dat);
           
          } else {
            this.loading = false;
            this.$refs.ModalMensaje.Mensaje('Error de conexión.','Error!', '#', 'danger')
          
           
          }
         
          this.loading = false;
        });
    },
```

quiero hacer la misma solicitud con flutter pero solamente obtengo un error 400, creo que es porque no envio el form correctamente:

```
Future <String> ingresarReclamosArtefactoQuemado(

    String tokenGoogle, 
    String codLink, 
    String apellido, 
    String nombre, 
    int dni, 
    double pumc, 
    double medidor, 
    double? celular, 
    String email, 
    String fechaDano, 
    String descripcion, 
    String esPersonal, 
    String fechaHoraPersonal,
    String apellidoPersonal, 
    String nombrePersonal,
    List<List<TextEditingController>> artefactosQuemados,
    File imageFrenteDNI,
    File imageDorsoDNI,
    File imageFactura

  ) async {

    print ("Ingreso en el provider");

    var request = http.MultipartRequest('POST', Uri.parse('${principalUrl}Claim/ArtefactoQuemado'));

    request.headers['Content-Type'] = 'multipart/form-data';
    request.headers['recaptchaToken'] = tokenGoogle;

    request.fields["Apellido"] = apellido;
    request.fields["Nombre"] = nombre;
    request.fields["DNI"] = dni.toString();
    request.fields["PUMc"] = pumc.toStringAsFixed(2); // Especifica 2 decimales
    request.fields["NumeroMedidor"] = medidor.toStringAsFixed(2); // Especifica 2 decimales
    request.fields["Celular"] = celular != null ? celular.toStringAsFixed(2) : ''; // Verifica si es null antes de convertirlo
    request.fields["Email"] = email;
    request.fields["FechaDaño"] = fechaDano;
    request.fields["Descripcion"] = descripcion;
    request.fields["PersonalEdeseTrabajando"] = esPersonal;
    if (esPersonal == "SI")
    {
      request.fields["NombrePersonalEdese"] = nombrePersonal;
      request.fields["ApellidoPersonalEdese"] = apellidoPersonal;
      request.fields["FechaPersonalEdese"] = fechaHoraPersonal;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < artefactosQuemados.length; i++) {

        List<TextEditingController> innerList = artefactosQuemados[i];
        
        for (int j = 0; j < innerList.length; j++) {
        
          TextEditingController controller = innerList[j];

          if (j == 0)
          {
            request.fields["ArtefactosQuemados[$i][NumeroOrden]"] = (i + 1).toString();
          }
          if (j == 1)
          {
            request.fields["ArtefactosQuemados[$i][Tipo]"] = controller.text;
          }
          if (j == 2)
          {
            request.fields["ArtefactosQuemados[$i][Marca]"] = controller.text;
          }
          if (j == 3)
          { 
            request.fields["ArtefactosQuemados[$i][Modelo]"] = controller.text;
          }
          if (j == 4)
          {
            request.fields["ArtefactosQuemados[$i][NumeroSerie]"] = controller.text;
          }
           
          print('Elemento en posición [$i][$j]: ${controller.text}');
        
        }
    }

    request.files.add(await http.MultipartFile.fromPath('image', imageFrenteDNI.path, contentType: MediaType('image', 'png')));
    request.files.add(await http.MultipartFile.fromPath('image', imageDorsoDNI.path, contentType: MediaType('image', 'png')));
    request.files.add(await http.MultipartFile.fromPath('image', imageFactura.path, contentType: MediaType('image', 'png')));
    
    try {
      
      var response = await request.send();

      var responseBody = await response.stream.bytesToString();

      var decodedResponse;

      if (responseBody.isNotEmpty) {
        decodedResponse = json.decode(responseBody);
        // Resto del código de manejo de la respuesta
        print (decodedResponse);
      } else {
        decodedResponse = 'No hay nada en el responseBody';
      }

      return decodedResponse;

    } catch (e) {
      print('Error al enviar la solicitud: $e');
      
      return (e.toString());
    }
  }
```